# Why are comment permalinks for django-comments-xtd going to example.com in Wagtail?

Tags: django, comments, wagtail, django-comments

I'm setting up comments in Wagtail using [django-comments-xtd](https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and one thing I'm having trouble figuring out is why my comment permalinks keep going to https://example.com/news/bloggy-test-post/#c1 instead of https://localhost:8000/news/bloggy-test-post/#c1.

I found a user with a similar issue in the Wagtail Google group who discovered that they had "example.com" set as their site in Wagtail admin. But I have only one site in my settings and it's currently set to "localhost" with a port of 8000.

[Screenshot of the Wagtail admin  site showing there is one site set to localhost with a port of 8000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqC4f.png)

I searched all my files and libraries for "example.com" and the only other setting I found was the BASE_URL setting in base.py. I tried changing that to http://localhost:8000 and the comment permalinks are still being directed to "example.com".

Is there another setting I'm missing? Or another way I'm supposed to get the URL?

Currently, I have this code for grabbing the url in my models.py file:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return self.get_url()
```

This is the comments section code from my template:

```
    {% get_comment_count for page as comment_count %}

      <p>
      <a href="{% pageurl page %}#comments">
        {{ comment_count }} comment{{ comment_count|pluralize }}
      </a>
      {{ comment_count|pluralize:"has,have" }} been posted.
    </p>

    {% render_xtdcomment_tree for page %}
    {% render_comment_form for page %}
```

And this is (hopefully) the pertinent piece from comment_tree.html from django-comments-xtd:

```
<h6 class="mb-1 small d-flex">
    <div class="mr-auto">{{ item.comment.submit_date }}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{% if item.comment.url and not item.comment.is_removed %}<a href="{{ item.comment.url }}" target="_new">{% endif %}{{ item.comment.name }}{% if item.comment.url %}</a>{% endif %}{% if item.comment.user and item.comment.user|has_permission:"django_comments.can_moderate" %}&nbsp;<span class="badge badge-secondary">{% trans "moderator" %}</span>{% endif %}&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="permalink" title="{% trans 'comment permalink' %}" href="{% get_comment_permalink item.comment %}">¶</a></div>
    <span>
      {% if not item.comment.is_removed %}
        {% if perms.comments.can_moderate %}
          {% if item.flagged_count %}
            <span class="badge badge-danger" title="{% blocktrans count counter=item.flagged_count %}A user has flagged this comment as inappropriate.{% plural %}{{ counter }} users have flagged this comment as inappropriate.{% endblocktrans %}">{{ item.flagged_count }}</span>
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if allow_flagging and item.flagged %}
          <i class="fas fa-flag text-danger" title="{% trans 'comment flagged' %}"></i>
        {% elif allow_flagging %}
          <a class="mutedlink"
             href="{% url 'comments-flag' item.comment.pk %}">
            <i class="fas fa-flag" title="{% trans 'flag comment' %}"></i>
          </a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if perms.comments.can_moderate %}
          <a class="mutedlink"
             href="{% url 'comments-delete' item.comment.pk %}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt" title="{% trans 'remove comment' %}"></i></a>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
  </h6>
```

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I added another site under "Sites" just to see if creating a new site would fix things. When there are two sites, "localhost" and "site.localhost", the URLs behave fine and go to the appropriate sites. If I remove one of those sites though, it reverts to using "example.com." So I'm guessing now there's something up with the multisite settings that I need to adjust or remove. I don't need a multisite. I think it came in the default demo project though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django has its own optional [Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/sites/) which is distinct from Wagtail's concept of sites. In the standard Wagtail project template this is turned off (i.e. `django.contrib.sites` is left out of INSTALLED_APPS) but your project may have it enabled, particularly if you integrated Wagtail into an existing Django project. Like Wagtail, Django's site records are kept in the database, and I suspect this is where the `example.com` reference is hiding - if you have the Django admin site enabled (as distinct from the Wagtail one), you should find a Sites model listed in there.

Digging into the django-comments-xtd and [django-contrib-comments](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments) code shows that the URL returned by the `{% get_comment_permalink %}` tag is ultimately handled by the `django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut` view, which is indeed [listed as making use of the Django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/sites/#how-django-uses-the-sites-framework).

As for why adding a second Wagtail site circumvents the problem: when Wagtail generates page URLs, it will prefer to return local URLs without the domain (e.g. `<a href="/news/bloggy-test-post/">`) when it can do so unambiguously - as is the case when only one Wagtail site is defined. Once you add a second site, it switches to a full URL including the domain - and at that point, Django recognises that it's been passed a full URL and doesn't try to apply its own site logic to 'fix' it up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I do have django.contrib.sites installed for my user authentication and I definitely didn't realize the Django admin and the Wagtail admin could co-exist. But now that you've pointed it out, it makes sense. The Django admin was indeed already set up in my urls.py and installed apps, so I just logged in and there was the offending "example.com". Everything's working well now with the links. Thank you so much. This was driving me mad.